# Negative Values when calculating time of a java date

Tags: java, datetime

just a question what i am doing wrong. I have this code:

```
    public static int berechneSekundenwert(String datum, String zeit) throws ParseException {

    Date dt = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
    dt = df.parse( datum+" "+ zeit); 
    int gesamtzeit = (int)dt.getTime();
    return gesamtzeit;
}
```

Now my import format is:

- 09.11.2019 01:30:17

  What i want to do is calculate the time passed for these dates, so i
  can later sort them by time. But i get negative values?!

  Example output (passed time, date, daytime):

  - -2120215336 30.09.2019 12:03:35
  - 1757321960 25.09.2019 16:06:25
  - -2111322336 30.09.2019 14:31:48
  - -1281127040 21.08.2019 12:05:36
  - -1280681040 21.08.2019 12:13:02
  - 377782960 09.09.2019 16:54:06
  - 1301386664 09.11.2019 01:30:17
  - 710621960 13.09.2019 13:21:25
  - 712564960 13.09.2019 13:53:48

Shouldn't they all be positive, since java states, that the getTime function measures the time since 01.01.1970

Anyone knows what i did wrong?

Comment: Well... you downcast the timestamp (`(int)dt.getTime();` which is a 64-bit `long`) to an (32-bit) `int`. A quick calculation (`2^31 / 1000/ 60 / 60 / 24`) shows that 32 bit is only enough to separate roughly 25 days without overflow. Use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: And you should be using the newer `java.time` API over the (effectively deprecated) older `java.util.Date` and associated APIs - they have the ability to calculate the time passed more accurately

Comment: To further expand on @MadProgrammer's comment, see https://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Well, actually I'd point to [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) tutorial, as JodaTime is in "maintenance only" mode

Answer (score 5):

Computers use something called a [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp#Digital_timestamps) to represent dates.  In Java, [`Date::getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the milliseconds passed since `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` up to the date in question as `long` (64-bit integer).

In the code presented, this value is narrowed down to an `int` (32-bit integer). By narrowing the `long` to an `int`, the highest 32 bits get cut of. The largest value representable by an `int` is [`2^31 - 1`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). A quick calculation shows that:

```
(2^31 - 1)      (milliseconds)
/ 1000          (milliseconds per second)
/ 60            (seconds per minute)#
/ 60            (minutes per hour)
/ 24            (hours per day)
= 24.8551348032 (days)
```

This means that after roughly 25 days, the `int` [will overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) (as it is defined in the [Two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Not to mention that a later point in time could have a lower value than an earlier point in time, thus the negative values.

To fix this issue<sup>1</sup>, I would suggest to define `gesamtzeit` as `long`.

---

Two remarks on your code:

- `java.util.Date` is regarded as outdated. I would suggest to use [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) instead.
- I would suggest to use English in the source code, only exception being you use domain-specific words that cannot (well) be translated to English.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is only a temporary fix. All representation with a fixed number of bits will eventually overflow. In fact, all representation with any memory constraint at all will overflow eventually. I leave it up to the reader to find out when a 64-bit integer will overflow</sub>

Comment: The questioner may have very good reasons for coding in German, we don't know. I have worked in more than one place where coding in my own language rather than English was a strict requirement. Code posted on Stack Overflow, an English language web site, ought of course be a minimal reproducible example created for that purpose and in English.

Comment: @OleV.V. hence the hint to the domain-specific words :) It should always be a conscious decision and never a "I am too lazy to look this word up"

Comment: Note that technically, this isn't _downcasting_, which is providing the compiler with more specific information about an object's type; it's a _narrowing conversion_, which by definition risks data loss.

Comment: Huh. Now that you say it... true. Thanks @chrylis-onstrike-! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- See [correct Answer by Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605308/642706) about [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing) versus [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)).
- Use only modern *java.time* classes, never `Date`/`SimpleDateFormat`.
- Consider the crucial issue of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).
- Educate the publisher of your data about the importance of (a) including zone/offset info, and (b) using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats.

Code:

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "09.11.2019 01:30:17" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) 
)
.atOffset(
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
)
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/iJzh5U).

> 1573263017000

## Details

The [correct Answer by Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59605308/642706) addresses your specific question as to why the invalid negative numbers. But you have other problems.

### ISO 8601

> Now my import format is: 09.11.2019 01:30:17

I suggest you educate the publisher of this data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defining formats to use when communicating date-time values as text.

### Legacy date-time classes

You are use terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date` or `SimpleDateFormat`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

### Moment

Apparently you want to get a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC. But doing that requires a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

Your input does not meet this requirement. Your input is a date and a time-of-day but lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone.

So, take your example of `09.11.2019 01:30:17`. We cannot know if this is 1:30 in the afternoon of Tokyo Japan, or 1:30 PM in Paris France, or 1:30 in Toledo Ohio US — which are all very different moments, several hours apart on the timeline.

So we must first parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). This class represent a date and time without any concept of offset or zone.

```
String input = "09.11.2019 01:30:17" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Perhaps you know for certain the offset or zone intended by the publisher of this data. If so:

- Suggest to the publisher of this data that they include the zone/offset info within their data.
- Apply a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Perhaps you know for certain this input was intended for UTC, that is, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To get a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z convert to the basic building-block class [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Interrogate for a count of milliseconds since epoch.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Understand that your original code ignored the crucial issue of time zone & offset-from-UTC. So your code implicitly applies the JVM's current default time zone. This means your results will vary at runtime, and means you likely have incorrect results too.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

why you downcast the return value of`getTime()`?

just make you method return `long` instead of `int`

and replace this line

```
int gesamtzeit = (int)dt.getTime();
```

with

```
long gesamtzeit = dt.getTime();
```